# Codificador e Decodificador de caracteres especiais em HTML

Tags: php, html

Como posso complementar o código abaixo para codificar e decodificar um texto que tenha acentuações ou símbolos para código HTML?

No caso eu fiz o codificador mais alem de não estar muito eficiente não estou sabendo fazer o decodificador para retornar o texto original.

```
<?php

function htmlconversor ($texto)  {
$ htmlcodificado = htmlentities($texto, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
 
return $htmlcodificado;
 
}
 
echo $valor = htmlconversor("Ação para conversão de áãé etc para código html");
 
// Pega o resultado e decodifica de html code para normal
echo "Converte o texto para código html ".htmlspecialchars_decode($valor);
 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o código abaixo:

```
<?php

function html_encode($content, $doubleEncode = true)
{
    return htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
}

function html_decode($content)
{
    return html_entity_decode($content, ENT_QUOTES);
}

$texto_codificado = html_encode("Ação para conversão de áãé etc para código html");
var_dump($texto_codificado);
var_dump(html_decode($texto_codificado));

?>
```